# Query Linkedin API for post like/share/comment count

Tags: linkedin-api

Not sure if this is even possible to do judging from the docs and Googling around.

Could somebody point me in the right direction to query a post based upon its ID and return information about that post

Answer (score 0):

You can query linked-in API endpoint https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/historical-status-update-statistics
And use (time,like-count,impression-count,click-count,comment-count,share-count,engagement,unique-count) at the end of url like this:

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/historical-status-update-statistics:(time,like-count,impression-count,click-count,comment-count,share-count,engagement,unique-count)?time-granularity=day&start-timestamp={someEpochTime}&end-timestamp={anotherEpoch}&update-key={someUpdateKey}&format=json

- update-key is optional: if not include an update key, it will give you stats for all updates

And the response will be like this:

```
{
"shareCount": 0,
"clickCount": 1,
"engagement": 0.014084507042253521,
"likeCount": 0,
"time": 1532563200000,
"impressionCount": 71,
"commentCount": 0,
"uniqueCount": 36
}
```

Comment: This answer uses LinkedIn API version 1. As of 2019, the version is deprecated and no longer works.